# Regular supergraphs of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

For every (finite simple) graph there exists a regular supergraph, even with the original graph as an induced subgraph.

Both versions (chronologically first the induced one, then the normal one with a reduced number of additional vertices needed) were proven by known graph theorists in I believe the sixties, but I fail to find the papers again and I would like you to help me find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced version of the problem is solved by Erdős and Kelly in ["The minimal regular graph containing a given graph"](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f233/1e88db6e8560f3e63c8b5b06b58cd6f9c854.pdf) (1963).

The other version is solved by Akiyama in ["Regular graphs containing a given graph"](https://eudml.org/doc/141303) (1983).

Comment: thanks to you I could find the other one. Added it so I can accept the answer